# How to import different version of the same jar?

Tags: maven

My project needs to import two different version of the same jar and they are incompatible.
How can I solve it with maven? Thanks.

Comment: Can you add some more details please? What jar? What exactly do you mean by "incompatible"?

Answer (score 0):

Having two different versions of the same jar is usually a bad idea, because they may share the same classes with a Fully Qualified Domain Name, such as com.example.MyClass.

There is no way for a normal classloader will be able to distinquish between the two versions of the classes, so you are likely to face other problems as well.

That said, though...

You can use the `dependency:copy` goal to grab explicit artefacts and place them somewhere in your project. For explicits, see the docs: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html